# Can't open "inspect" in forced installed chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

If I install chrome extension via registry [ExtensionInstallForcelist](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions) then I can't open DevTools (F12), and also "Inspect" is disabeled (Ctrl+shift+l)

[image]

[image]

How can I inspect force installed extensions?

Comment: There's probably no way. Just in case, see if you have another policy that disables devtools.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is to prevent tampering

Extensions installed by group policy are intended to resist tampering by experienced users. If users were permitted to inspect force-installed extensions, they could modify stored data, remove event handlers, and change JavaScript variables along with other forms of tampering.

For example, a parental-control extension that stored the elapsed browsing time in local storage could easily be tampered with by decreasing the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

To debug chrome extensions force installed via registry or GPO, you should set the correct value for the `DeveloperToolsAvailability` key. By default, it is `0`. You need `1`.

[DeveloperToolsAvailability | Chrome Enterprise Policy List & Management | Documentation](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DeveloperToolsAvailability) :

> 0 = Disallow usage of the Developer Tools on extensions installed by enterprise policy, allow usage of the Developer Tools in other contexts
>
> 1 = Allow usage of the Developer Tools
>
> 2 = Disallow usage of the Developer Tools